# Select json column using JPA native query with MemSql

Tags: java, spring, jpa, singlestore

I have a table in a `MemSql` database which contains a column of type `JSON`.

I am trying to execute the following query.

```
select tweet from tweets_json;
```

The `tweet` column is the `JSON` column.

Here is the code I am using to execute this query.

```
public List<String> getTweets(){
    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select tweet from tweets_json");
    List<String> resultList = query.getResultList();
}
```

I am expecting the result to be a list of strings and each string to represent the JSON.

The problem is that I am getting the string converted to as a single `Character` object which contains only the first character of the JSON `{`.

The result is always a list of Character with the open curly bracket symbol regardless the type of the list item I am using.

I tried using `List<Object[]>`, `List<String[]>`, `List<Object>`, `List<JsonElement>` and all returing the same result.

I even tried to not specify the type of the list elements and return just a List and the result still the same.

How can I get the whole JSON and what is the root cause of this issue?

Comment: There a similar question here [Store Retrieve Json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32819485/store-retrieve-json-data-to-from-mysql-5-7-database-using-hibernate) which may help you a lot.

Comment: You tagged your question with [tag:mysql], but you mention only MemSQL. If you are not using MySQL, you should remove that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use JSON_EXTRACT_STRING function.

```
select JSON_EXTRACT_STRING(tweet,0) from tweets_json;
```

The exact functiona definition is:

```
JSON_EXTRACT_<type>(json, keypath)
```

You can find examples here:
https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v6.7/json_extract_type/

and here

[Reading JSON from MEMSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902777/reading-json-from-memsql)

With respect to the common case when `EntityManager`/`HibernateSession` is used, a [custom Hibernate Type is necessary](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/).

Comment: Adding json user type (as adviced here https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/) solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked out for me.

Use `CAST(tweet as CHAR(1000))` in native sql query for typecasting json

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select CAST(tweet as CHAR(1000)) from tweets_json");
```

This will return you `char[]` array which can be cast to `String` and can be used further.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest an alternative approach - you could retrieve the column as a string and thereby not need Hibernate to understand anything about JSON:

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select tweet :> text from tweets_json");
```

That's typecasting the JSON field to `text`, a string datatype (you could also use varchar or whatever as needed).

The result returned is the same (just a string) either way, but this way Hibernate should be able to understand that it's a string.